# Create a split control like the one in the Browser's address bar

Tags: android, search, address-bar

I want to create a search box with the search button directly to the right of the `EditText` without any spacing, like how like the address bar on the internal browser application looks (see image below).  Is this possible or do I need to create it myself?

[Screenshot of the Android browser search bar http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/7338/gp2.png](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/7338/gp2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'll take a bit of customization; you can look at the source here in the open source tree:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/res/res/layout/search_bar.xml

The relevant bits are:

```
<view ...
  ...
  android:background="@drawable/textfield_search"
  ...
/>

<Button 
  ...
  android:background="@drawable/btn_search_dialog"
  ...
/>
```

As you can see, it's using custom drawables (i.e. not `@android:drawable...`).

And yes, this can all be found using Hierarchy Viewer, as per Pentium10's response.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) to get the view from the Internal Browser